# React hooks states aren't updating in log

Tags: reactjs

If I write

```
function Component() {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const request = () => {
    setLoading(true)
    console.log(isLoading)
    setLoading(false)
    console.log(isLoading)
  }
}
```

It will log out 'true' both times. Why isn't the state updating in the console? Eventhough it works fine in the DOM.

`this.setState({ ...}` will show the new state value

Comment: You aren't waiting for `setLoading` to complete. Your log statement is likely completing before the `setLoading` has finished updating the state,

Comment: Thats wrong, but anyways, it wasn't what I was looking for. I updated the question

Comment: `isLoading` isn't mutated by `setLoading`. Its value will only be updated in the next render. `setLoading` is also asynchronous.

Answer (score 4):

Setting a new value in state by using `setState` or `useState` hook is an asynchronous process.

If you want to log the new value once it has changed, you have to couple it with the `useEffect` hook

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(isLoading)
}, [isLoading]);
```

Comment: Well, works correctly, yes. But there is a big different, cause you don't have to call componentdidupdate, to log the changes

Comment: I never said that you had to call `componentDidUpdate` :) By default `useEffect` hook is called every time your component is rendered. by passing a second argument like I did here, you specify that you only want to execute it when the value of `isLoading` is changing. So indeed, `useEffect` can replace in functional components what you were doing previously in `componentDidUpdate` in class components.

Answer (score 0):

Arnaud's answer is 100% correct, but what confused me when playing around with this stuff was that calling `setState` twice didn't have the same effect as trying to `console.log` directly after an update.

This is because of how React handles state updates internally, and even though your log may be wrong, your state is actually updated appropriately.